# Append Text using jquery from checkboxlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working in ASP.NET project. And my task is to append the **Checkbox** text to the **TextBox**. **Checkboxes's** text are bound from Database values in **CheckBoxList**.

```
protected void prbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=nci;Integrated Security=true";
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    List<string> minire = new List<string>();
    string sql = "SELECT distinct PRIMARY_MINI_REGION FROM customers";
    myConn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConn);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    minire.Add(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    group12.DataSource = dt;
    group12.DataTextField = "PRIMARY_MINI_REGION";
    group12.DataValueField = "PRIMARY_MINI_REGION";
    group12.DataBind();
    string[] grpary = prgrp.Text.Split(';');

    foreach (var items in grpary)
    {
        if (items != "")
        {
            li.Add(items.ToString());
            if (li.Contains(items.ToString()))
            {
                group12.Items.FindByText(items.ToString()).Selected = true;
                //group12.Items.FindByText(items.ToString()).Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can any of you please help me how to do it in jquery.Currently i appended text using stringbuilder using C# as like

```
protected void group_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem l in group12.Items)
    {
        if (l.Selected)
        {
            li.Add(l.Text);
        }
    }
    foreach (var i in li)
    {
        si.Append(i.ToString() + ";");
    }
    //if (prgrp.Text == "")
    //    prgrp.Text = si.ToString();
    //else
    prgrp.Text = si.ToString();
}
```

once i select checkbox means it have to append text.and once i unchecked it means,content have to be deleted from textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this snippet helps you out:

```js
$(function() {
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  // Reset output:
  $("#output").html('');
  
  // Repeat for all checked checkboxes:
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){ 
   
   // Get values:
   var existingText = $("#output").html();
   var textToAppend = $(this).val();
   
   // Append seperator (';') if neccessary:
   if(existingText != '')
   {
    existingText = existingText + ";";
   }
   
   // Print out append value:
   $("#output").html(existingText + textToAppend);
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Select:</h2>
<input type="checkbox" value="Jan"/>Jan
<input type="checkbox" value="Feb"/>Feb
<input type="checkbox" value="Mar"/>Mar
<input type="checkbox" value="Apr"/>Apr

<h2>Output:</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I just corrected the code snippet.

Comment: Help me with this link please....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832368/repeative-values-occur-in-autocomplete-jquery/

Comment: Thanks 5T..can u help me in reverse process too..if i typed that check box value in textbox means..it have to check the appropriate checkbox

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(
    $('.checkBoxCommunClass').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).get(0).id;
        if ($('input[id=' + id + ']:checked').length > 0)
            $('#resultTextInput').val() = $('#resultTextInput').val() + $(this).val();
    }));
```