# Repeative values occur in Autocomplete jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working in ASP.NET Project.My task is to Prevent the repative values occured in Textbox.Textbox is bound with autocomplete and appending text from checkboxlist as like in the below picture
! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OPwgmPG6QpTHBTdVlFaldRaEE/view?usp=sharing
After i appended the content from checkbox list to textbox means it is repeating value,if i typed it inital time it won't.And my task is to show unique values based on the textbox content.
My project files are in the below link..please help me out guys

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OPwgmPG6QpS3NMNElGN2k4RzQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my answer I gave you in the other thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28828842/4569271) I extended my solution to only display unique values:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    // Reset output:
    $("#output").html('');

    // remeber all unique values in this array:
    var tmpArray = new Array();

    // Repeat for all checked checkboxes:
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {

      // Get value from checkbox:
      var textToAppend = $(this).val();

      // Check if value from checkbox was added already:
      if (jQuery.inArray(textToAppend, tmpArray) == -1) {

        // add entry to array so it will be not added again:
        tmpArray.push(textToAppend);

        var existingText = $("#output").html();

        // Append seperator (';') if neccessary:
        if (existingText != '') {
          existingText = existingText + ";";
        }

        // Print out append value:
        $("#output").html(existingText + textToAppend);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Select:</h2>
<input type="checkbox" value="Jan" />Jan
<input type="checkbox" value="Jan" />Jan
<input type="checkbox" value="Jan" />Jan
<input type="checkbox" value="Feb" />Feb
<input type="checkbox" value="Feb" />Feb
<input type="checkbox" value="Feb" />Feb
<input type="checkbox" value="Mar" />Mar
<input type="checkbox" value="Mar" />Mar
<input type="checkbox" value="Mar" />Mar

<h2>Output:</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Based on your description, I am not sure if this is the solution you were looking for? But maybe it helps.